# Security things to do in input data

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

I have a website build in CodeIgniter framework. The website contain a lot of forms for different purposes. I am submitting these forms directly to a controller function.

1. What are the things I should apply in this input before I save it to database through the model?
2. If I directly send this data without doing anything, what will be the security risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use form_validation 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Best way will be if you will set rules for each field
like this

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
```

And you don't need to use any special escape

Or try to understand how to use PDO in CodeIgniter

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/03/codeigniter-with-pdo

Comment: Yes I am using form validation and also for example I am saving data like this   $to_insert = array('name' => $input['name'],'code' => $input['code'])
            $this->db->insert('table_name', $to_insert);  should I use any escape functions to this inputs ??